# Pass opened file name to function

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building a small app where I am doing some calculations and want to save the variables and results into a *.csv file.

My desire is to open the *.csv file via a menu point in Tkinter and, after calculations done, save the results with a button to the *.csv file.

What I am not able to do is to save the data, as I am passing the file name in the wrong way.
I have tried to assign the file name to a variable, declare it as global but have not find any solution.

This is the code snippet requested, not just the 2 functions:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
# Used for styling the GUI
from tkinter import ttk
from math import *
import csv
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from datetime import datetime

# global database

class windows(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        global database
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
         # Adding a title to the window
        self.wm_title("calculator and database")
        
        #
        tire_menu = Menu(self)
        self.config(menu=tire_menu)

        def command_open():
            filename = fd.askopenfilename(
                title = 'Select database',
                filetypes = [("CSV files", "*.csv")])

            showinfo(
                title = 'You have selected',
                message = filename)

            database = filename
            return(database)

        def command_new():
            extensions = [("csv file(*.csv)", "*.csv")]
            file = asksaveasfile(filetypes=extensions,
                defaultextension=extensions)

            headerlist = [
                "Date",
                "Track"]

            database = file.name
            with open(database, "w") as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow(headerlist)

        # create a menu item
        file_menu = Menu(tire_menu)
        db_menu = Menu(tire_menu)

        tire_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu = file_menu)
        file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.quit)

        tire_menu.add_cascade(label="Database", menu = db_menu)
        db_menu.add_command(label="New DB", command=command_new)
        db_menu.add_command(label="Open DB", command=command_open)

        # creating a frame and assigning it to container
        container = tk.Frame(self, height=600, width=800)
        # specifying the region where the frame is packed in root
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        # configuring the location of the container using grid
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # We will now create a dictionary of frames
        self.frames = {}
        # we'll create the frames themselves later but let's add the components to the dictionary.
        for F in (MainPage, SidePage, CompletionScreen):
            frame = F(container, self)

            # the windows class acts as the root window for the frames.
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        # Using a method to switch frames
        self.show_frame(MainPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        # raises the current frame to the top
        frame.tkraise()


class MainPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        title_main = tk.Label(
            self,
            text="calculator")
        title_main.config(font=("Times 18 bold"), bg="white")
        title_main.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=5)

        def savetodb():
            data = [
            datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),

            ]
            with open(database, "w") as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow(data)

        ## Create reference tire pressures frame
        frame_reference = tk.LabelFrame(
            self,
            text = "1: Enter reference data: ")
        frame_reference.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, columnspan = 2)

        lbl_track = Label(
                    frame_reference,
                    text = "Track: ",
                    font = 'Times 11',
                    justify = tk.CENTER)
        lbl_track.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        # entries for database save
        ent_track = Entry(
            frame_reference,
            justify = tk.CENTER,
            width = 23).grid(row=0, column=1)

        btn_savetodb = Button(
            frame_reference,
            text="Save to DB!",
            font = 'Times 11 bold',
            command=savetodb)
        btn_savetodb.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=5)

class SidePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the Side Page")
        label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        switch_window_button = tk.Button(
            self,
            text="Go to the Completion Screen",
            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(CompletionScreen),
        )
        switch_window_button.pack(side="bottom", fill=tk.X)


class CompletionScreen(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Completion Screen, we did it!")
        label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        switch_window_button = ttk.Button(
            self, text="Return to menu", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainPage)
        )
        switch_window_button.pack(side="bottom", fill=tk.X)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    testObj = windows()
    testObj.mainloop()
```

Could you please provide some help?

Comment: can you try to use the file name without space?

Comment: and pass the filename through func variable

Comment: def savetodb(database):
    data = [
    ]
    with open(database, "w") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(data)

Comment: Declare `database` as global inside `command_open()` should work as long as it is executed before `savetodb()`.

Comment: I have tried to declare database as global within the function, the class and outside the class. It does not change anything.

Comment: @Alexander honestly, I believe the problem lies here somewhere. With the first code I just select the desired file I want to write to. With the second function, I would like to write my calculated data into the selected file of the first function.

Comment: @AndreiFilep  The problem is that you don't know how to solve your problem and you are asking for help doing that... I am offering to help you, but you still think you know better?  Good luck.  BTW acw1668 is 100% right.  If you knew how to set a global variable that would solve your problem.

Comment: I don't know why my suggestion does not work for you. So it is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: @AndreiFilep  Hey what do you know, it turns out you were wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `global database` in wrong place.  It should be put inside `command_open()` as I said in my comment:

```py
class windows(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        def command_open():
            global database
            ...
            database = filename
            return database
        ...
    ...
```

---

However I would suggest to use a class variable inside `windows` class instead of global variable, so that it can be accessed using `controller.database` inside `MainPage` class:

```py
class windows(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.database = None
        ...
        def command_open():
            ...
            self.database = filename
            return self.database
        ...
    ...
...

class MainPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ...
        def savetodb():
            ...
            with open(controller.database, "w") as f:
                ...
        ...
    ...
```

Note that you have to change all occurrences of `database` to `self.database` inside `windows` class.